# Error with the javascript in PHP and googleMap API

Tags: javascript, php

I am using the Javascript source in PHP , and the source is using googlemap Javascript API. The code seems to be without errors, but when I insert this line into the code I get an error 500 internal server error, and the page does not show anything on it, no HTML or map:

```
echo 
"var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);";
```

The code should be in quotation marks right? All the rest of the Javascript code looks fine, just when I add this line, all the page stops working, and this is exactly the line which renders the map.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
echo 'var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);';
```

Comment: @MaziarTasbihi Try that because you've improperly quoted your string, which is a syntax error.

Comment: I removed the double quotes and inserted the single code, the page now loads fine, there is no browser error, but there no googlemap also showing. This line functions as the main map element, how if it is not functioning, there will be also no googlemap. So there is a problem, we cannot just change the double quote to single quote, what do you think might be the problem ?